# In Borderlands 1, how can I see the chat?

Tags: borderlands

I can't see the chat in Borderlands 1.

I press Y, then I type something in the msg prompt, I hit enter, nothing happens. My co-op partner can't see it either.

A Google doesn't yield any results that would suggest that this is an issue. What is going on here?

Comment: Is 'Y' the right key? I'm at work so I can't check, but I thought the talk key was usually 'T'. (Though I suppose the fact that you're seeing a message prompt rules that out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the text ("msg") that is already in the prompt. Then, hit enter and the chat will appear on the right-hand center of the screen ...